# App engine local version file system limitation

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working on a local copy of an app. When trying to upload a file, I suddenly received a filenotfound exception. I'm using app engine and google cloud storage. Deleting and rebuilding the local datastore did not help.

```
    Jun 2, 2013 1:26:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
    WARNING: /_ah/upload/ahJjbGlxdXJlYXBwLXN0YWdpbmdyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgnDA:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\XX\Eclipse Workspace\XXX\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\encoded_gs_key:Y2xpcXVyZS1kZXZlbG9wbWVudC1waG90b3MvcFVQcldCcmZPZE1QWUFCcUlJUkVwQQ (The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved the problem by restarting everything - browser, IDE, deleting datastore, clean and rebuild project etc.

Comment: Deleting the `\WEB-INF\appengine-generated` folder solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the local filesystem in GAE. Use the blobstore or Cloud Storage.

Comment: He specified **I'm working on a local copy of an app**. Of course App Engine SDK uses the local file system when developing - that's how it simulates storage.